# Find which cell value has the most number of rows?

Tags: excel

The excel spreadsheet at my work has a column for date and I'm trying to find out which date shows up the most. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes. Try a Google search for "count of dates in Excel"; there are lots of solutions.

Comment: https://exceljet.net/formula/most-frequently-occurring-text

Comment: On top of the other suggestions, if they are just plain date cells, which are numbers, you can use MODE (now MODE.SNGL) to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be found [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/most-frequently-occurring-text), assume your dates are in the range, of say, `A2:A1000`, you could use the following formula:

```
=INDEX(A2:A1000,MODE(MATCH(A2:A1000,A2:A1000,0)))
```

Comment: Should mention it needs to be an **array formula.**